# is quartz able to render pdfs without other libraries?

Tags: iphone, ios, macos, pdf, quartz-graphics

I found CGPDFDocumentRef that should be the way to render pdf's on OSX and iOS. Is it right? Without any other library or Adobe SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quartz does not implement the complete ISO 32000 PDF standard. For example, iOS devices do not render JPEG2000 compressed images at all.

Comment: but are these JPEG2000 images used often in pdf's, like technical books for example?

Comment: JPEG2000 isn't that common, unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

Yes Quartz can natively render PDFs. See the [quartz demo](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/QuartzDemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007531) sample code